# Why does <a> inside <ul> inside <a> behave so strangely?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

In the project I work on, I came across a `<ul>` tag which was nested inside an `<a>` tag (the click event was handled by JavaScript). I tried adding another `<a>` tag inside in the unnumbered list and something very strange happened.

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<a test="foo">
  <ul>
    <li>
      Before link
      <a>Link</a>
      After link
    </li>
  </ul>
</a>
```

When you inspect it browser tools, you will see that this is actually rendered by the browser like this:
[image: F12 tools screenshot]

`<ul>` is not actually wrapped in `<a>`. There are three copies of the `<a test="foo">` tag, one empty one just before the `<ul>`, another empty one as an immediate child of `<ul>`, and another one wrapping the contents of the `<li>` element, up to the expected `<a>Link</a>`.

I tested this in Chrome and Firefox and the same thing happens in both browsers.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. [Use a validator](https://validator.nu/). Anchors are not allowed to be descendants of other anchors.

The browsers are attempting to recover from your error.